# Is there a Linux kernel boot parameter to configure an IPv6 address?

Tags: linux, configuration, ipv6, boot-loader

I know there is a parameter named `ip` which lets you configure IPv4 addresses on the Linux kernel through the boot loader. That looks like the following:

```
ip=192.0.2.1::192.0.2.62:255.255.255.192::eth0:none
```

I'm looking for an equal parameter for IPv6 configuration. I couldn't find anything about this in the kernel documentations.

**Update**: Because of a lot of you asked why I would need this: The idea to use a kernel configuration came up related to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/445038/debian-wheezy-ipv6-isnt-configured-with-ifup-post-up-hook) problem. I suspect the regular boot-up interface configuration is not done, because the interfaces are already up. The reason for this could be that I'm using a pre-boot environment with a Dropbear SSH server to allow me to unlock my encrypted root partition. The IP addresses for this environment are configured through GRUB with the `ip=` parameter. There is no DHCP or Router Advertisement available on that Ethernet segment and as this is the uplink segment provided by a large hosting company, there is no way to change that fact.

Comment: In fact, there isn't one. You can enable IPv6 autoconfiguration, but that is probably not what you are looking for. Is there a specific result you're trying to achieve (i.e. what is the reason you want to avoid IPv6 configuration in the machine's initialization process?)

The `ip=` parameter was initially meant to configure the IP stack before the kernel tries to mount a NFS root filesystem, but I feel that you should rely on something else to achieve the same result with IPv6 (most probably, SLAAC).

Comment: I know about SLAAC. But I need to set it up manually.

Comment: My feeling is that since the introduction of the "early userspace" feature (initramfs either embedded in the kernel or as a separate file like traditional initrd), you are encouraged to do such things as configuring IP addresses there instead of with special one-off command line parameters. That's probably why there is a historical command line parameter for IPv4 but none was added for IPv6.

Comment: At what time in the boot process do you need it to be set?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that you need this. What _exactly_ are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've updated my question to give some detail on the reasons why I went looking for this option.

Comment: @aef What did you end up doing? I have exactly the same circumstances that you have.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I had the same question like aef in mind, but for a different purpose: Unlocking a LUKS-encrypted root partition with a dropbear SSH daemon running from initramfs and accessing that one by IPv6. IMHO that's a very valid and in future rather common reason to want this. Actually Debian's dropbear-initramfs package even reminds me: "Don't forget to check your "ip=" kernel bootparameter to match your desired initramfs ip configuration." The desired IP configuration is clearly an IPv6 one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, but if you want this, you'll have to build it yourself, or more likely, reuse someone else's implementation.

The `ip=` command line option you've been using is actually part of the kernel's boot code for [mounting an NFS root filesystem](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt). It has never been extended for IPv6, and there is no kernel boot parameter for configuring IPv6 at boot time.

That said, some Linux distributions such as Red Hat have [implemented](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.2_Release_Notes/installation.html) their own `ipv6=` boot parameter for their installation media. You may be able to reuse this code in your custom initramfs.

Answer (score 4):

According to Fedora, the ip= parameter can be used with IPv4 or IPv6 addresses. IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in square brackets. If you need both, you can use multiple ip= options on the kernel line as in:

... ip=[2001:db8::dead:beef]::[2001:db8::cafe:babe]:64::eth0:none ip=192.0.2.5::192.0.2.1:255.255.255.0::eth0:none ...

Comment: This answer is contradicting the accepted answer. This may be due to the accepted answer being outdated. To remove any doubt about which answer is correct, it would be a good idea to include a link to the source of this information.

Comment: This is probably an evolution of the thing RedHat implemented, which was mentioned in Michael Hampton's answer. I tested it in Debian Jessie and it didn't work. I am still looking for a generic Linux way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

All your boot parameters are available via /proc/cmdline after boot.
So, you can just set up all needed options via custom mkinitcpio hook, which would parse cmdline in search for specific param. You can use ipv6= like ip= one.

Comment: Yeah. I could build it myself, but that was not what I'm looking for. Still thanks for the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how it looks like in Hetzner's Rescue mode (Debian 11):

```
root@rescue ~ # cat /proc/cmdline
initrd=rescue/current-amd64/initramfs.cpio.zst nfsdir=[2a01:4ff:ff00::b007:1]:/nfs RFILE=rescue-amd64-bullseye-v002.ext2 HASH=$5$XuSCY.REDACTED net.ifnames=0 vga=0x317 lang=de quiet IP6=REDA:CTED:4a:28c5:: IP6MASK=64 IP6GW=fe80::1 config_url=https://admin-robot.your-server.de/admin/api/boot/order/redacted BOOT_IMAGE=rescue/current-amd64/vmlinuz BOOTIF=aa-bb-cc-ee-7b-e6
```